# Q_Object with no type

Tags: c++, qt

The error I am receiving:

> g++ -c -g -I/usr/lib/qt-3.3/include TCPEchoServer.cpp
>   Product.h:22: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of âQ_Objectâ with no type
>   Product.h:24: error: expected â;â before âvoidâ
>   make: *** [TCPEchoServer.o] Error 1

I'm using QT 3.3.
What am I missing...? T___T

```
#include <string>
#include <qtimer.h>
#include "HandleTCPClient.h"
#ifndef PRODUCT_H
#define PRODUCT_H
#include <qobject.h>
#include <qgl.h>

class Handler;

//Define ourselves a product class
class Product
    {

        Q_Object

        void startTimer();

    public:
        Product();

        string seller, itemName, description, highestBidder;
        double price, min, buyingPrice, currentBid;
        int time;
        bool isSold;
        Handler *handler;

        void setHandler(Handler *h);

    public slots:
        void setProductToSold();

    };

#endif
```

Comment: Some nitpicks... why is some but not all of the code ifdefed?  Also, you probably want a slightly more specific ifdef.  In addition, you have the includes thrown together in what appears to be a random order.  I usually find it helpful to include standard headers all together, then Qt headers all together, and finally my local headers all together.  This way I can see at a glance what Qt objects are used, for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing the correct case for the macro, it should be `Q_OBJECT`.

Answer (score 2):

And, A QObject should inherit in some way from the class `QObject`...

Or was this not the case with QT3 ?